# My discord.py bot hosted on heroku does not work

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I hosted my discord.py bot on heroku, *Build Succeeded*, and *Deployed*. 
The code works on my *VSC* but not on heroku.

**requirements.txt :**

```
discord.py==1.3.4
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pandas
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

**Procfile :**

```
worker: python bot.py
```

I don't know what is the problem.
Can please anyone tell me what to revise or what's wrong?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

**I did :**

```
$ heroku logs --tail
```

**and I got :**

```
2020-07-30T03:30:00.853064+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 3, in <module>
2020-07-30T03:30:00.853284+00:00 app[worker.1]: import requests
2020-07-30T03:30:00.853316+00:00 app[worker.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2020-07-30T03:30:00.964329+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-07-30T03:30:01.011352+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Sorry for the fool question.

Comment: add `requests` to `requirements.txt` or run locally `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Your project depends on the Python module `requests` which is not installed in your deployed environment.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue it sounds like you need to add the requests module to your requirements.txt. To obtain this you can run the following command in your console:

```
pip show requests
```

Make a note of the version number and append the following to your requirements.txt file:

```
requests==x.y.z
```

Where `x.y.z` is replaced with the version you obtained from using `pip show requests`.

***The general process of hosting a bot on Heroku:***

If you want to host your bot on Heroku the steps I take are:

**requirements.txt**

You can obtain this by running the following command in your console:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will write all the required Python modules into the file for you with their respective versions. (This should also find and add your missing "requests" module)

**Procfile**

Inside this file, you will only need:

```
worker: python bot.py
```

"python bot.py" is what will be run on Heroku to start your bot. Although you have done this fine.

**Heroku Resources**

On the Heroku website access the dashboard for your app. Then select the "Resources" tab.

Next, there should be the contents of your Procfile. Click on the pen on the right hand side, enable the switch to allow Heroku to start the worker.

If you have any issues with hosting your bot, please reply to my suggestion and I'll be happy to help.